# Evaluate exponential fraction limit.

Tags: limits

I think the following limit should have an exact solution, but I'm not really sure how to approach the problem.

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} \frac{\exp(-\frac{x^2}{b}) - \exp(-\frac{a^2}{b})}{|x - a|}$$

Comment: Ever heard about derivatives?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the two-sided limit exists? Or do you want to find the one-sided limit?

Comment: Well, using l'Hopital rule doesn't give me much
$$= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{-2\frac{x}{b}exp(-\frac{x^2}{b})}{sign(x-a)}$$
Continuing to use derivatives yields infinity. I'm pretty sure that's incorrect. Plus I'm looking for an exact evaluation. 

I'm interested in the one-sided limit, I edited the question.

Comment: Forget l'Hopital. I was hinting at the very _definition_ of a derivative. I vaguely recall that some kind of limit was involved there.

Comment: Haha, I don't know how I missed that, but thanks so much for making me see!